# How to get meta description content using Goutte

Tags: php, web-crawler, goutte

Can you please help me to find a way to get a content from meta description, meta keywords and robots content using Goutte. Also, how can I target `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">` and `<script>`?

Below is PHP that I used to get `<title>` content:

```
require_once 'goutte.phar';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();


$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://stackoverflow.com/');

$crawler->filter('title')->each(function ($node) {
$content .= "Title: ".$node->text()."";
echo $content;
});
```

Here is a link to Goutte - https://github.com/fabpot/goutte

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
$crawler->filterXpath('//meta[@name="description"]')->attr('content');
```