# Laravel Goutte cannot get meta tags

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, laravel-5, goutte

Im using `Goutte\Client` in laravel 5.2 and it seems that it can't get the meta tags content but can get the title, links, etc.

This returns empty string.

```
$parse = $htmlParser->request('GET', 'http://www.sample.com');
$parse->filter('meta');
```

Output:

```
  private 'nodes' => 
    array (size=20)
      0 => 
        object(DOMElement)[289]
          public 'tagName' => string 'meta' (length=4)
          public 'schemaTypeInfo' => null
          public 'nodeName' => string 'meta' (length=4)
          public 'nodeValue' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'nodeType' => int 1
          public 'parentNode' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'childNodes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'firstChild' => null
          public 'lastChild' => null
          public 'previousSibling' => null
          public 'nextSibling' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'attributes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'ownerDocument' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'namespaceURI' => null
          public 'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'localName' => string 'meta' (length=4)
          public 'baseURI' => null
          public 'textContent' => string '' (length=0)
```

This returns the title.

```
$parse = $htmlParser->request('GET', 'http://www.sample.com');
$parse->filter('title');
```

Output:

```
  private 'nodes' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(DOMElement)[289]
          public 'tagName' => string 'title' (length=5)
          public 'schemaTypeInfo' => null
          public 'nodeName' => string 'title' (length=5)
          public 'nodeValue' => string 'Test title' (length=36)
          public 'nodeType' => int 1
          public 'parentNode' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'childNodes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'firstChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'lastChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'previousSibling' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'nextSibling' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'attributes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'ownerDocument' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
          public 'namespaceURI' => null
          public 'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'localName' => string 'title' (length=5)
          public 'baseURI' => null
          public 'textContent' => string 'Test title' (length=36)
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674916/how-to-get-meta-description-content-using-goutte

Answer (score 0):

@moisesgallego on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674916/how-to-get-meta-description-content-using-goutte) post was able to answer my question though playing around with it, I was able to find another as well. So basically it loops through all the meta tags and returns the name and content as an array.

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
$meta = $crawler->filter('meta')->each(function($node) {
    return [
        'name' => $node->attr('name'),
        'content' => $node->attr('content'),
    ];
});
```